# PHP: not saving apostrophe

Tags: php

I have a php page that saves some data to my database.  It works with all strings with special characters (. , ? !) but it doesn't work with apostrophes (').

This is my php:

```
$message = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']));
$safe_variable = mysqli::escape_string($message);

$i_sql = "INSERT INTO tableName ( id_user, username, message) VALUES ( '".$id_user."', '".$username."', '".$safe_variable."')";
$i_res = mssql_query($i_sql);
```

I've tried with and without this line:

```
$safe_variable = mysqli::escape_string($message);
```

And I've read that I should use `mysql_real_escape_string` but that it is no longer supported and I should use `mysqli::escape_string` instead.

What am I doing wrong in my PHP or what should I be using to be able to save apostrophes?

**Note:**

`$message` is `I'm` when I test.

Comment: you shouldn't be escaping manually. use a placeholder+prepared statement

Comment: It looks like you are using the MySQL quote escape function for an MSSQL server. Those are two **COMPLETELY** different database engines. MySQL escapes single quotes with \' and MSSQL escapes single quotes with ''. You can't just mix and match functions like that.

Comment: You ought to switch to PDO and prepared statements. That way you don't have to worry about slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`escape_string()` cannot be called statically with `mysqli::escape_string($message)`

Furthermore `mssql_query($i_sql);` doesn't make any sense here as it looks like your're using mysql as db.

The code can be fixed like this:

```
// This is the object that represent the connection to the db
$conn = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db_name');

$message = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']));
$safe_variable = $conn->escape_string($message); // fixed here

$i_sql = "INSERT INTO tableName ( id_user, username, message) VALUES ( '".$id_user."', '".$username."', '".$safe_variable."')";
$i_res = $conn->query($i_sql); // fixed here
```

The above, of course, assuming you're using mysql as database.

Anyway I would strongly suggest to use prepared statements instead of escaping strings.